# How to assign an HTML attribute value from a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, angularjs

I have an HTML `<a>` tag where a button is defined. I want to change the button color, based on an entry from a database. I would like to know what method should be used here.

Below is my HTML code. I want to override the `btn-orange` color, which is defined in the CSS. My business logic does not allow me to hard code the color here.

```
<a ng-href="{{user.id == user_id ? site_url+'message' : 'javascript:void(0);'}}" class="btn btn-orange btn-block send-message" id="user{{event_users.indexOf(user)}}" ng-if="redirect && loged_in_user"
        data-reciver-image="{{user.profile_picture}}" 
        data-reciver-name="{{user.first_name+' '+user.last_name}}" 
        data-reciver-id="{{user.id}}" data-sender-image="{{loged_in_user.profile_picture}}"     
        data-from-profile-id="{{loged_in_user.profile_id}}" 
        data-to-profile-id="{{user.profile_id}}"
        ng-if="loged_in_user" ng-click="showMEssageBox('#user'+event_users.indexOf(user), user.id)">
    {{user.id == user_id ? 'My Messages' : 'Message'}}
</a>
```

I am using a MySQL database.

Comment: what is already tried?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

You could do something like

```
<a ng-class="{'btn-red': user.id < 5, 'btn-orange': user.id > 5}"
 class="btn btn-block send-message">
```

The idea here is to bind classes based on the model, just like you would for `ng-if` or `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<a ng-class=" {{user.id < 5 ? 'btn-red' : 'btn-orange'}} "
 class="btn btn-block send-message">
```